# Grouping about equal sizes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to programming in VBA and I was interested in completeing a small project that I completed on paper into code.

Problem:
Given a dataset of 26 rows (Alphabetically A-Z) and their respective record count, group them into n groups (n>0) equally based on count fairly where each letter is unique to that group. So if group 1 had A,B,C then other groups can't use that letter.

When I solved this one paper this was my thought process:

1. Copy the data to a different part of the page so I can manipulate the data.
2. Sum the total count for all the records (autosum A~Z_count)
3. Sort the data based on total record count, largest to smallest
4. Find the percent of the total for each record (count/total)
5. Selfishly distrubte the data so that while the group data percent sum is less than the total_percent/number of groups begin to check each letter and save that data to the excel sheet to the side of the main data.

Below is my pseudocode for this problem in c++ and the data I used and solved by hand. Like I said I'm very new to VBA so I'd like to create a macro that will auto solve this if I ever have another document in the future.

```
int totalcount = sum(letter_index)
int index_percent = count/total 

int i = 1
int group_i_data_percent_sum = 0.0

int total_percent = 1
int n_groups = 5 //Can vary based on user desired input


while (group_i_data_percent_sum =< total_percent/n_groups)
{
    //Check to see if our value is less than total_
    if((index_percent + group_i_data_percent_sum) < 
    total_percent/n_groups)
    {
        //Add on the data
        group_i_data_percent_sum= current_letter_percent + group_i_data_percent_sum

    //Store a list of the accepted letters added together.
    }
    //Otherwise store the list into a data table and increment to next letter
}

//Repeat for all n_groups till all letters are uniquely added to groups.
```

My handwritten solution for the groups of 5 and 6.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz2sgKh9NVmVUGlfZ1NETlJwaTg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to answer this question because it's a good opportunity to explain some of the capabilities of VBA. The macro code generator has its place in recording keystrokes, but so many posts on here are simply pastes of the auto-generated code with a question like: "How do I loop this?"

It's true that those who wish to develop applications wouldn't use VBA, but that's not to say VBA is a lesser language. VBA is really pretty decent ... provided the developer steps away from keystroke recordings and dips his toe into the waters of object oriented programming.

The real strength of VBA comes when the developer 1) reads the data from Excel, 2) completes all the data processing, and 3) only then, writes the results back to Excel.

The code below shows you how VBA could do that with the task you have outlined. I have to say I don't think your steps are the best solution for the task, but I'll leave that outside of this post. What I can show you is not how to translate your pseudo code directly into VBA, but how you can use some of VBA's objects to achieve the same thing. BTW, I don't think your pseudo code matches your handwritten solution - if you take Group 1, for example: 'S' + 'C' = 0.1683710 whereas your code wouldn't accept any total above 0.1666667 so 'S' and 'C' wouldn't make the same group programmatically.

Anyhow, on to the code ...

First of all, add two `Class Modules` (Insert -> Class Module). Name the first `cLetterFields` and add the following code:

```
Public Letter As String
Public Frequency As Integer
```

Name the second class `cAcceptedFields` and add the following code:

```
Public TotalFrequency As Integer
Public MemberLetters As Collection
```

In your module, add the following procedure:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Const BOOK_NAME As String = "My Book.xlsm" 'rename to your book
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1" 'rename to your sheet
    Const READ_ADDRESS As String = "A2:B27" 'amend as suits
    Const WRITE_ADDRESS As String = "D2" 'amend as suits

    Dim readArray As Variant
    Dim writeArray() As Variant
    Dim values As cLetterFields
    Dim accepted As cAcceptedFields
    Dim groupList As Collection
    Dim letterList As Collection
    Dim nGroups As Integer
    Dim totalFrq As Integer
    Dim maxGroupFrq As Integer
    Dim largestGroupSize As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim v As Variant

    ' Read the values from the worksheet
    readArray = Workbooks(BOOK_NAME). _
                Worksheets(SHEET_NAME). _
                Range(READ_ADDRESS).Value2

    ' Sort the values
    readArray = QSort2D(readArray, 1, UBound(readArray, 1), 2, False)

    ' Populate the collection of letters and their frequencies
    ' by assigning values to the cLetterField class.
    Set letterList = New Collection
    For i = 1 To UBound(readArray, 1)
        Set values = New cLetterFields
        values.Letter = readArray(i, 1)
        values.Frequency = readArray(i, 2)
        letterList.Add values, Key:=values.Letter
        totalFrq = totalFrq + values.Frequency
    Next

    nGroups = 6 'amend the acquisition of this as you need.

    ' Populate the groups.
    largestGroupSize = 0
    maxGroupFrq = Int(totalFrq / nGroups)
    Set groupList = New Collection
    For i = 1 To nGroups

        ' Initialise the group.
        Set accepted = New cAcceptedFields
        Set accepted.MemberLetters = New Collection
        accepted.TotalFrequency = 0
        groupList.Add accepted

        ' Loop through the letters and add them to the group if they fit.
        For Each values In letterList
            If accepted.TotalFrequency + values.Frequency <= maxGroupFrq Or i = nGroups Then
                accepted.MemberLetters.Add values.Letter
                accepted.TotalFrequency = accepted.TotalFrequency + values.Frequency
                ' Remove the accepted letter from the list.
                letterList.Remove values.Letter
                ' Get the group size to dimension our write array.
                If accepted.MemberLetters.Count > largestGroupSize Then
                    largestGroupSize = accepted.MemberLetters.Count
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Next

    ' Write the data to the worksheet.
    ReDim writeArray(1 To largestGroupSize + 2, 1 To nGroups + 1)
    writeArray(1, 1) = "Counsellor"
    writeArray(largestGroupSize + 2, 1) = "TOTAL"
    i = 0
    For Each accepted In groupList
        i = i + 1
        writeArray(1, 1 + i) = i
        j = 1
        For Each v In accepted.MemberLetters
            j = j + 1
            writeArray(j, 1 + i) = v
        Next
        writeArray(largestGroupSize + 2, 1 + i) = accepted.TotalFrequency
    Next

    Workbooks(BOOK_NAME).Worksheets(SHEET_NAME).Range(WRITE_ADDRESS). _
        Resize(UBound(writeArray, 1), UBound(writeArray, 2)).Value = writeArray

End Sub
```

You'll see that I have referenced a function called `QSort2D` which is just a routine I often use to sort 2 dimensional arrays. If you'd like to do your own sorting then delete that line. If you want my sorting function then leave the line in and paste the following code into your module:

```
Private Function QSort2D(sortArray As Variant, _
                         bottomIndex As Long, _
                         topIndex As Long, _
                         sortIndex As Long, _
                         ascending As Boolean) As Variant

    Dim lowIndex As Long
    Dim hiIndex As Long
    Dim swapValue As Variant
    Dim tempValue As Variant
    Dim y As Long


    lowIndex = bottomIndex
    hiIndex = topIndex
    swapValue = sortArray((bottomIndex + topIndex) \ 2, sortIndex)

    Do While lowIndex <= hiIndex

        If ascending Then

            Do While sortArray(lowIndex, sortIndex) < swapValue And lowIndex < topIndex
                lowIndex = lowIndex + 1
            Loop
            Do While sortArray(hiIndex, sortIndex) > swapValue And hiIndex > bottomIndex
                hiIndex = hiIndex - 1
            Loop

        Else

            Do While sortArray(lowIndex, sortIndex) > swapValue And lowIndex < topIndex
                lowIndex = lowIndex + 1
            Loop
            Do While sortArray(hiIndex, sortIndex) < swapValue And hiIndex > bottomIndex
                hiIndex = hiIndex - 1
            Loop

        End If

        If lowIndex <= hiIndex Then
            For y = LBound(sortArray, 2) To UBound(sortArray, 2)
                tempValue = sortArray(lowIndex, y)
                sortArray(lowIndex, y) = sortArray(hiIndex, y)
                sortArray(hiIndex, y) = tempValue
            Next
            lowIndex = lowIndex + 1
            hiIndex = hiIndex - 1
        End If

    Loop

    If bottomIndex < hiIndex Then sortArray = QSort2D(sortArray, bottomIndex, hiIndex, sortIndex, ascending)
    If topIndex > lowIndex Then sortArray = QSort2D(sortArray, lowIndex, topIndex, sortIndex, ascending)

    QSort2D = sortArray

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance it was a treat to go through the object oriented stylization on VBA. Sorry for the explaination, when I did it by hand I changed some values at the last minute to try to evenly distribute the data a little more. I really appreciate the help!